# Error: render function or template not defined in component: NuxtLink

Tags: api, vue.js, express, nuxt.js, nodemailer

I added the api to my Nuxt.js 2.16.3 project.
And after that I tried to run the nuxt generate command. I got this error:
Error: render function or template not defined in component: NuxtLink.
It's very strange because everything was fine with the links until I plugged in the API.

```
//nuxt.config.js code:
serverMiddleware: [{ path: "/api", handler: "~/server-middleware/index.js" }],
```

```
//Nuxt component:

methods: {
    submit() {
      this.loading = true;
      axios
        .post("/api/send-email", {
          email: this.email,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.success = true;
          this.name = "";
          this.email = "";
          this.job = "";
          this.message = "";
          this.loading = false;
          if (this.error) this.error = false;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.error = true;
          this.loading = false;
          if (this.success) this.success = false;
        });
    },
  },
```

```
//server-middleware/index.js

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const express = require("express");
const { urlencoded } = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.post("/send-email", function (req, res) {
  const { email } = req.body;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    pool: process.env.MAIL_POOL,
    host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
    secure: process.env.MAIL_SECURE,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  let options = {
    from: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
    to: email,
    subject: "New message!",
    text: "",
  };

  transporter.sendMail(options, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json();
      return console.log(`${err} in middleware`);
    }
    console.log(info.messageId);
    res.status(200).json();
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I thought I had made a mistake somewhere in the code of the components and tested them... but the error is still there. All NuxtLink links work fine as they did before I added the API.

I think I washed something out when I wrote the code. After all, I'm a react developer and not really familiar with nuxt and vue.

Maybe try something like app.listen() and then specify as proxy server? I think the error is that nuxt thinks the api component belongs to the client side, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Error: render function or template not defined in component: NuxtLink
    at io (D:\upwork\n3on-website\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.prod.js:1:66370)
    at po (D:\upwork\n3on-website\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.prod.js:1:70229)
    at uo (D:\upwork\n3on-website\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.prod.js:1:69871)
    at bn.ao [as renderNode] (D:\upwork\n3on-website\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.prod.js:1:67155)